# How to allow people from different domains to access my web service?

Tags: wcf, cors

I have an OData web service, but people cannot use it because of CORS.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxx.xxxx.com/OData/OData.svc/Employee'. Origin http://xxx.xxx.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

What should I do to allow people use my service from other domains?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, it works if I use jsonp.

One thing that I'm wondering why it works because I think that I only added custom header in my web.config file.

Is that all that I have to do on the server-side or do I have to write more code to support CORS?